# Unable to enable Transfer acceleration on AWS s3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I am using AWS S3 Bucket to back up huge files. My technical knowledge is limited. The upload speed is slow & from some basic research I found out that I need to enable "Transfer acceleration" to speed up uploads.

But when I try enabling transfer acceleration, I get an error

[image: 1]

Please guide me like I am five-year-old.

I checked the documentation & tried to follow the instructions. Made some changes in IAM but still I am unable to enable it.

I am the owner of the account.

Answer (score 0):

Your current user doesn't have permissions to update Transfer acceleration settings. From your error I can see that you need **s3:PutAccelerateConfiguration** permission.

If this is your only user and this is a personal account follow this steps:

1. Go to your user in IAM(/iam/home#/users/{username})
2. Click **add permissions** button
3. Go to **Attach existing policies directly**
4. Search for **AmazonS3FullAccess**
5. Click **Review**
6. Click **Add permissions**
7. Check if you are able to edit Transfer acceleration

You can remove other permissions that you have already set for S3.

---

Otherwise follow these steps:

1. Go to your user in IAM(/iam/home#/users/{username})
2. Click **add permissions** button
3. Go to **Attach existing policies directly**
4. Click **Create policy** button
5. Get the settings to be like this:[image]
6. Skip tags
7. Choose a name for the policy
8. Create policy
9. Attach the policy

This is better because it's more specific and you don't give any unnecessary permissions.

---

Let's see if these options help you to solve the problem.